# How do I direct my Mac back to saving iPhone backups in original default MobileSync/Backup folder

Tags: iphone, terminal, backup

I tried to get my Mac to save iPhone backups directly to an external hard drive by entering a version of the script below into Terminal, that is specific to me;

ln -s /Volumes/ExternalHardDriveName/iPhoneBackup/Backup/ ~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync

I did get the symlink folder but the backup didn't work.

I have since updated the OS to Catalina and now I don't have a MobileSync folder. I have read that you can undo the redirection scripted above, by simply deleting the Symlink folder, but I don't have a MobileSync folder, therefore also do not have the symlink folder I created.

I recreated a MobileSync folder and Backup folder in its correct location, hoping finder would find it and back up to there but when I tried a backup, an error message appears saying "Could not backup the iPhone Liz’s iPhone because the backup was corrupt
Delete the backup for this iPhone, then try again."

Also, next to the Manage Backups button in the iphone Finder window, it says "Unknown"

Can anyone tell me how to tell my computer to revert to saving iPhone backups in the original default location?

Thanks, Liz

Comment: What if you created the mobile sync folder and then tried a local backup, what happens then?

Comment: Can you paste 
open ~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync/Backup/
into your Terminal to make sure that your newly created Backup folder opens?

Comment: Thanks guys. I have since fixed it. 

I Spotlight searched MobileSync on the internal HD and three came up. The new one I created in the wrong location - Mac HD/Library/Application Support, the original one, which is in Users/Lizzy/Library/Application Support, and a third. 

The original one had the backup folder which I had renamed OLD Backup. I changed that name back to Backup and it worked. Phew! 

I was manually looking for MobileSync in the wrong place as my Users Library does not show up when I simply look for in manually in Finder. It only appears if I Spotlight search. Thanks.